# Need to design a network for a medium size business with wireless and wired connections

Tags: networking

I need help in designing a network for a 100-room hotel where all the guests require internet access. We also have business desktops that require wired connections in our offices.

I need guidelines on how to set this up to have an efficient system where guests do not have access to our business systems while both have internet access.

I need suggestions on the design as well as the equipment to use. As this is my first time asking a question here, I am not sure even if i am asking the right question. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, resource or product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

This kind of situation is where you need to hire a competent network administrator, consultant or contractor company to do the work for you. That kind of setup is very far outside the kind of thing that can be covered in a site like this. Please look for skilled and experienced local contractors or hire a full time IT staff to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of project that many of us do for a living. You shouldn’t expect to get it for free.